# Windows 10 installation issue

Tags: windows, media

I want to do clean install using windows media creation tool but after
Getting files ready for the installation it need restart but after that it goes to the selecting language again keeps looping?

Comment: Please kindly check if the following article is helpful: [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool: Everything You Need to Know](https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/windows-10-media-creation-tool)

Answer (score 1):

Your boot order in your BIOS is set to load the installation media before the installed OS. Either adjust your boot order in Bios or remove the Windows 10 Media when it restarts so it doesn't attempt to boot it again.